# How would I find isolated zeros in binary array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, binary

If I have binary number like this - 0b1110111110011011011001000, and I would spread by 5 bit, then it looks like:

```
11101 # 29  
11110 # 30  
01101 # 13  
10110 # 22  
01000 # 8
```

except 0110 /1000 in the right downside, every 0 would be considered as isolated zeros, so at first, I coded to find '101', to find

?1?
101
?1?   - it would find isolated zero in the array.

Array is [29, 30, 13, 22, 8] and by using string,

```
def find_closed(array,width = 5):
    new_arr = ['1'*(width+2)]+['1'+bin(x)[2:]+'1' for x in array]+['1'*(width+2)]
    for each in range(len(array)):
        a = new_arr[each+1].find('101') +1
        if a and int(new_arr[each][a]) &int(new_arr[each+2][a]):
            return each+1,a
    return False
```

so the code will point out (1,4), row 4, column 1.

well, I made it by bit shifting,

```
def bit_closed(array,width = 5):
    new_arr = [2**(width+2)-1]+[2**(width+1)+2*x+1 for x in array]+[2**(width+2)-1]
    for each in range(len(array)):
        for shift in range(width):
            if not ((new_arr[each+1]>>shift)-5)%8 and (new_arr[each]>>(shift+1))%2 and (new_arr[each+2]>>(shift+1))%2:
                return each+1, width - shift
    return False
```

Actually I believe it could be even shorter by using list loops. Anyway, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose the 2D-list, [[],[],...] as an input,

```
def matrix_closed(small):
    org = small[:]
    for objs in org:
        objs.append(1)
    org.append([1]*len(objs))
    n=0
    for lines in org[:-1]:
        x=0
        for points in lines[:-1]:
            if not points and all((org[n-1][x],org[n+1][x],org[n][x-1],org[n][x+1])):
                return n,x
            x+=1
        n+=1
    return False
```

It would work faster rather in python, since python does not intendly support binary array oneself. time costs more for the function calling, rather than bit opperating.